# Help with html select replacement

Tags: html-select

I hate default select control, that's because it can't be styled in IE using CSS.
This is why I developed a new select control from scratch, using HTML + CSS + JavaScript.
I did a great job in the past two days matching CSS and HTML together, but today I discovered a bug wich looks very hard for me to fix.

In IE 7, when I have tow controls on the same page, the one from top does not overlay the one from bottom.

See the image: coolrgb dot com/files/select-help.jpg

Download the demo page (HTML + CSS + Javascript): coolrgb dot com/files/select-help.zip

Please help me, this control looks so nice for me and I want to use it on all my projects from now on. This bug killed my hopes and lot of time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give each control the same z-index, then you will not have control over the stacking order.

I would suggest modifying your control to behave more like a real SELECT element: only one can be open at a time, or losing focus causes it to close. Alternately, you can set a high z-index when the control has focus, and a lower one when it does not.

Another thing to look out for: try putting some other controls like radio, checkbox, and select under your control. You might find that IE also will not hover over those even if you give them a different z-index (as @grawity explained in his answer). This is why you'll typically see widget demos displayed on top of these elements, as shown here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

A typical hack to fix this is to use an iframe, but that probably deserves a different question altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much. Setting the z-index to something very big for the focused control on the onclick event worked perfect.
This page helped me: http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: After rereading the question, this answer now seems totally unrelated, but I'm keeping it here anyway.*

Not really an answer, but an attempt to explain:

In Internet Explorer, `<select>` tags are implemented as simple [windowed controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx), while all other elements are windowless controls (this allows them to be styled). That's why these tags are always on top and don't follow the z-order rules. (The drop-down menu part must be styleable so it's a windowless control, and so it shows under the main part.)

In Firefox all elements are windowless, and in IE8 they should be too.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, that's why I developed a new html select from scratch, and the bug is within this new control, not the default one

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you wrote your own control.